# Do user defined data types always cause implicit conversion to occur when fields of those UDDTs are used as predicates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, type-conversion, cardinality-estimates, user-defined-type

I have a database (from a vendor application) that for some unknown reason has a UDDT on almost every column, even when the UDDT is logically the same as the underlying type it implements. E.g. a column in this database might be of UDDT `bTinyInt(TinyInt)`.

Two tables in this database have columns that share the same exact UDDT. E.g. `TableA.Field1` is of type `bVarchar(VARCHAR(10))` and `TableB.Field2` is also `bVarchar(VARCHAR(10))`.

When I join these two tables together by the aforementioned fields, I notice a warning in the execution plan stating a Cardinality Issue because these fields are being implicitly converted to `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

Is it always the case that UDDTs get implicitly converted when used as predicates, even when comparing the same UDDT?

Also not sure if it matters as well, but the database these two tables belong to is of collation `Latin1_General_BIN`.

Comment: Can you include sample DDL and query that shows this behavior? I can't seem to repro from the information provided in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce any warnings or performance differences in this scenario, even when joining `bVarchar` to `varchar(10)`.  EG

```
create database tt 

alter database tt collate Latin1_General_BIN
use tt 
go
create type bVarchar from varchar(10)

create table a(id int primary key identity, b bVarchar, c varchar(10));
create table b(id int primary key identity, b bVarchar, c varchar(10));

with q as
(
  select top 1000000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
  from sys.messages, sys.objects 
)
insert into a (b,c) 
select concat(i%10000,'abc'), concat(i%10000,'abc')
from q;  

with q as
(
  select top 1000000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
  from sys.messages, sys.objects 
)
insert into b (b,c) 
select concat(i%10000,'abc'), concat(i%10000,'abc')
from q;  

go


set statistics time on
set statistics io on

select count(*)
from a
join b 
  on a.b = b.b

select count(*)
from a
join b 
  on a.c = b.c

select count(*)
from a
join b 
  on a.b = b.c

set statistics time off
set statistics io off
```

outputs

```
    SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 360 ms, elapsed time = 360 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row affected)
Table 'a'. Scan count 9, logical reads 4125, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 3510, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'b'. Scan count 9, logical reads 4125, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 2656, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 268 ms,  elapsed time = 117 ms.

(1 row affected)
Table 'a'. Scan count 9, logical reads 4125, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'b'. Scan count 9, logical reads 4125, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 297 ms,  elapsed time = 184 ms.

(1 row affected)
Table 'a'. Scan count 9, logical reads 4125, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'b'. Scan count 9, logical reads 4125, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 280 ms,  elapsed time = 111 ms.

Completion time: 2020-10-17T09:56:35.6734439-05:00
```

Comment: Hmm I'll have to revisit the case I ran into. It's possible they weren't the source of the performance issues I was experiencing but the execution plan definitely had implicit conversion warnings that specifically called out those UDDT fields. I'll try to post an update today with a reproducible example.

Comment: So I finally figured out what was going on. This Vendor system is so stupidly overcomplicated. The entities I was experiencing the Implicit Conversion warnings on we're out of the box views the Vendor created. Each view they created calls a function in the WHERE clause as a predicate. The function takes in a couple parameters to do a lookup on a meta-data table they created for heir own implementation of row level security. The function takes all it's parameters in as VARCHAR(30) even though there are all kinds of cases where the underlying type being passed in isn't VARCHAR. You win good sir.

Comment: To further complicate things, every entity in this system doesn't have a proper name, they are all 4 letter abbreviations, and are hidden behind multiple layers of views each with an abbreviated name. There are even some instances where they are doing remote querying, but that's another story for another time. Thanks for your input on my original question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance issue with `UDDTs` .
There is no Warning message when `UDDTs` is use in Predicate.

Reason :

```
select * from sys.columns
```

In this query notice the `system_type_id` & `user_type_id`.Sql optmizer already know and uses system Data Type.